# How to save the scanf input only if there's enough space in the array? How to reallocate array to let the scanf input fits in?

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, calloc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char *mystring = calloc(2, sizeof(char));

    scanf("%10[^\n]s", mystring);

    printf("\nValue: %s\nSize of array: %d\nAllocated space: %d\n",
           mystring, 2 * sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * strlen(mystring));

    free(mystring);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./"dyn_mem" 
laaaaaaaaaaa

Value: laaaaaaaaa
Size of array: 2
Allocated space: 10
```

This code can produce an undefined behavior if I enter in the `scanf` input a string bigger than array size. How can I *handle* this ?

Comment: This might be one reason people do not like C.  You have to count the number of elements first, allocate your memory and then read them.   However scanf reads from stdin and you cannot seek back to the start. Unfortunately using scanf is bad for exactly the reason you've described.   You need to use `getchar()` in a loop or `read()`.

Comment: You have specified that scanf will read up to 10 chararacters therefore `mystring` needs to have allocated memory with at least 11 chars to be used in this `scanf`. However you've allocated only 2 chars.

Comment: I know @isrnick . I did it on purpose, to test all these scenarios and trying to handle them.

Comment: In that case, if you must use these functions, the best I can think of is that you would have to make both `calloc` and `scanf` be set by a single variable with a set value, for that you would need a `size_t` variable for the size, and an auxiliary char array to store the format string made using `sprintf` with the size as an argument, to be used in the `scanf` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `mystring` is initialized to point to an allocated block of 2 bytes. Technically, you should test for memory allocation failure.
- the conversion format `"%10[^\n]s"` is incorrect: the trailing `s` should be removed, the syntax for character classes ends with the `]`.
- the number `10` means store at most 10 characters and a null terminator into `mystring`. If more than 1 character needs to be stored, the code has undefined behavior.
- the `printf` conversion specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%d`. If your C library is C99 compliant, use `%zu`, otherwise case the last 2 arguments as `(int)`.
- the sizes output do not correspond to the labels: the first is the allocated size, and the second is the length of the string.
- the `scanf()` will fail if the file is empty or starts with a newline. You should test the return value of `scanf()`, which must be `1`, to avoid undefined behavior in case of invalid input.
- `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

There are many ways to achieve your goal:

On systems that support it, such as linux with the GNU lib C, you could use an `m` prefix between the `%` and the `[` in the `scanf()` conversion format and pass the address of a `char *` as an argument. `scanf()` will allocate an array with `malloc()` large enough to receive the converted input.

Here is a modified version for linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *mystring = NULL;
    if (scanf("%m[^\n]", &mystring) == 1) {
        printf("Value: %s\n"
               "Length of string: %zu\n"
               "Allocated space: %zu\n",
               mystring, strlen(mystring), malloc_usable_size(mystring));
        free(mystring);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On POSIX systems, you could use `getline()` that reads a line into an allocated array.

On other systems, you would need to write a function that reads the input stream and reallocates the destination array as long as you don't get a newline or the end of file.

A common compromise is to make an assumption about the maximum length of the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    if (scanf("%1023[^\n]", buf) == 1) {
        char *mystring = strdup(buf);
        if (mystring) {
            printf("Value: %s\n"
                   "Length of string: %d\n",
                   "Minimum allocated size: %d\n",
                   mystring, (int)strlen(mystring), (int)strlen(mystring) + 1);
            free(mystring);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use `fgets()` to read a line from the input stream and strip the newline (if any). This approach has the advantage of not failing on empty lines.

Here is a simple implementation of `getline()` that should fit your needs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream) {
    char *ptr = *lineptr;
    size_t size = *n;
    size_t pos = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(stream) && c != '\n') {
        if (pos + 1 >= size) {
            /* reallocate the array increasing size by the golden ratio */
            size = size + (size / 2) + (size / 8) + 16;
            ptr = realloc(ptr);
            if (ptr == NULL) {
                ungetc(c, stream);
                return EOF;
            }
            *n = size;
            *lineptr = ptr;
        }
        ptr[pos++] = c;
        ptr[pos] = '\0';
    }
    return (int)pos;
}

int main() {
    char *mystring = NULL;  // must be initialized
    size_t size = 0;        // must be initialized
    int res;

    while ((res = my_getline(&mystring, &size, stdin)) >= 0) {
        printf("Value: %s\n"
               "Length of string: %d\n",
               "Allocated size: %d\n",
               mystring, res, (int)size);
    }
    free(mystring);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So there's not a portable way to do it. Also, can I dynamically allocate an array and if scanf can't find space, I reallocate the same array to let this have more space? Is `strdup` portable and usable in all systems (you say it's a POSIX thing)? Also, last thing, can all this be done with `realloc()` ?

Comment: @Mnkisd: `strdup()` is a standard function in POSIX, and will be added to the next version of the C Standard. Most systems already support it. If it is not available on your system, it is easy to rewrite. I added a sample yet efficient implementation of `getline` that uses `realloc` and should solve your problem. The difference from the `scanf()` approach is the newline a consumed by `getline()` and `my_getline()`, and the difference between `my_getline` and `getline` is this newline is not appended to the line read.

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1**

from [Kernighan and Ritchie 2nd ed](https://www.google.com/books/edition/C_Programming_Language/Yi5FI5QcdmYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=c%20the%20programming%20language&dq=c%20the%20programming%20language&printsec=frontcover) appendix B.1.4

```
char *fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream)
```

fgets reads at most the next n-1 characters into the array s, stopping if a newline is
encountered; the newline is included in the array, which is terminated by '\0'. fgets
returns s, or NULL if end of file or error occurs.

> replace `n` with `sizeof(char)*strlen(mystring)` in your code

**Option #2**

also from [Kernighan and Ritchie 2nd ed](https://www.google.com/books/edition/C_Programming_Language/Yi5FI5QcdmYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=c%20the%20programming%20language&dq=c%20the%20programming%20language&printsec=frontcover) appendix B.1.4

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream)
```

fgetc returns the next character of stream as an unsigned char (converted to an
int), or EOF if end of file or error occurs.

and manually put in a for loop with `sizeof(char)*strlen(mystring)` as the limit

Answer (score 0):

> This code can produce an undefined behavior if I enter in the scanf
>   input a string bigger than array size.

Yes.

> How can I "handle" this ?

By ensuring that you always pass `scanf` a pointer to an object of type appropriate for the corresponding conversion directive.  hat is always *your* responsibility as a C programmer.  For `s` and `[` directives, "appropriate" includes being large enough to accommodate all possible converted values.

It is easy enough to do that when the format expresses the maximum size of the input, either directly, as in the example, or parametrically.  And the format is under your control.  But if you need to handle input of unbounded size then `scanf` isn't up to the task, at least not by itself.  In that case, you need to implement a variation on guessing how much space you'll need, and acquiring more if that turns out not to be enough.  Among other things, that means being prepared to read the input in more than one piece, and probably obtaining space for it by dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. >and acquiring more if that turns out not to be enough. This is the part I don't know how to do. How can I "check" if there's not enough? How can I acquire more? I'm new to C but I'm very curious