# Is creating a long buffer and then strdup into a new variable the best way to save any input from scanf?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, scanf, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int buf[1024];
    if (scanf("%1023[^\n]", buf) == 1) {
        int *myarray = strdup(buf);     // strdup should use malloc to dynamically allocate basing on the length of string
        if (myarray) {
            printf("Value: %s\nLength of string: %d\nDynamically allocated space: %d\n", myarray, strlen(myarray), ( (strlen(myarray) + 1)*sizeof(int) ));  // the last one should be the value of the new dyn allocated "myarray" array
            free(myarray);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this the best way to avoid memorization problems with scanf?

Can I use realloc in some way instead of using strdup and buf?

**Does the part `(strlen(myarray) + 1)*sizeof(int)` correctly prints the size in bytes of the dynamically allocated `myarray` with strdup?**

Comment: Why is your buffer an `int` array if you are reading `char`s? Btw `strdup` is non-standard,, consider using `malloc` manually.

Comment: *"strdup should use malloc to dynamically allocate basing on the length of string"*. No. `strdup` dynamically allocates memory **as if** by using `malloc`, but it doesn't have the constraint of calling `malloc` directly.

Comment: I'm not aware about any _"memorization problems"_ with scanf. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @DarkAtom: `strdup` is a well-known POSIX function that we be included in the next version of the C Standard. If absent from the target system, it can be added easily.

Comment: I definitely know that :P I was just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I documented in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877680/how-to-save-the-scanf-input-only-if-theres-enough-space-in-the-array-how-to-re), the code in the question is a quick and dirty way to get a line of input from the user, but it has some limitations:

- it fails if the stream has an empty line
- long lines will be silently split in `1023` byte chunks.
- it leaves the newline pending in the input stream.

`getline` is available for this on POSIX systems, but it stores the newline at the end of the array if one was present in the stream.

Here is a simple implementation of `my_getline()` that behaves similar to `getline` but does not keep the newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream) {
    char *ptr = *lineptr;
    size_t size = *n;
    size_t pos = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(stream) && c != '\n') {
        if (pos + 1 >= size) {
            /* reallocate the array increasing size by the golden ratio */
            size = size + (size / 2) + (size / 8) + 16;
            ptr = realloc(ptr);
            if (ptr == NULL) {
                ungetc(c, stream);
                return EOF;
            }
            *n = size;
            *lineptr = ptr;
        }
        ptr[pos++] = c;
        ptr[pos] = '\0';
    }
    return (int)pos;
}

int main() {
    char *mystring = NULL;  // must be initialized
    size_t size = 0;        // must be initialized
    int res;

    while ((res = my_getline(&mystring, &size, stdin)) >= 0) {
        printf("Value: %s\n"
               "Length of string: %d\n",
               "Allocated size: %d\n",
               mystring, res, (int)size);
    }
    free(mystring);
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding your last question: *Does the part `(strlen(myarray) + 1)*sizeof(int)` correctly prints the size in bytes of the dynamically allocated `myarray` with `strdup`?*: No this expression is incorrect, there is no reason to multiply by `sizeof(int)`. There is no portable way to determine the size of the block allocated by `strdup()` (or `malloc`), it is only guaranteed to have an allocated size of at least `strlen(myarray) + 1` if the allocation was successful.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, why this? Why would malloc allocate more than what I want? For example, if I put 2*sizeof(int) it should allocate 2*4 bytes... why shouldn't it?

Comment: `malloc` will try and allocate the number of bytes you pass as an argument. For technical reasons, it may round this number up to a multiple of 16 or some other way and allocate some more bytes than what you ask for. There is no portable way to know that. In your question you write `(strlen(myarray) + 1) * sizeof(int)`: there is no reason to multiply by `sizeof(int)`, a string is an array of `char` and `char` is by definition a single byte in C. `strdup(buf)` should allocate `strlen(buf) + 1` bytes.