# Get input string for unkown size, how to stop taking input when a non-alphanumeric character is not on the string?

Tags: c, string, validation, malloc, user-input

Hello I'm trying to learn C and I'm working with DMA, I'm trying to create a program that takes an input string from the user but we don't know the maximum size (I want to allocate the memory on the heap) another thing I'm trying to do is that the string can only have alphanumeric characters, or maybe stop taking input when the string has a comma or dot entered by the user (is this possible?)

If you guys could suggest me a way to achieve this or point me in the right direction I would highly appreciate it.

thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, you need to show your code here if you're seeking for help. But for a short guidance, you need to allocate memory for an array dynamically ([referring this link for help](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/)) then loop the array and see if each character containing it is whether `isalnum()` or not - this requires `ctype.h` library.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and post an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal, you should read one byte at a time from the input stream with `getc()` or `getchar()` and store it into a destination array if alphanumeric, testing with `isalnum()` from `<ctype.h>`, reallocating the array as needed with `realloc()` and stopping on `EOF` and any other separator, possibly pushing this byte back to the input stream with `ungetc()`. Use an `int` variable to store the result of `getc()` to allow for proper detection of end of file. Don't forget to null terminate the destination array and return that to the caller, or `NULL` at end of file.

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878806/4593267) for examples of similar purpose.

Note that if you know a reasonable limit for the size of the input, you can use `scanf()`:

```
char buf[1000];
if (scanf(" %999[0-9a-zA-Z]", buf) == 1) {
    // handle the user input
    handle(buf);
    // read and discard the separator(s)
    scanf("%*[^0-9a-zA-Z]");
} else {
    // no pending word: either end of file or a non alphanumeric character pending
}
```

Note also that GNU systems have an extension that allows `scanf` to allocate the destination array to the appropriate size, only limited by available memory:

```
char *str;
if (scanf(" %m[0-9a-zA-Z]", &str) == 1) {
    // handle the user input
    handle(str);
    // free the allocated string
    free(str);
    // read and discard the separator(s)
    scanf("%*[^0-9a-zA-Z]");
} else {
    // no pending word: either end of file or a non alphanumeric character pending
}
```

Comment: @JeanBook: you can upvote and accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.